# Border is partially hidden on hover in Highcharts column and pie charts

Tags: css, svg, highcharts

When I hover over segment of a stacked bar or pie chart I want the segment to have a black border all of the way around. However, for stacked column and pie charts in particular one side of the hovered-over segment retains the white border separating it from the next segment:

[incomplete bar segment border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaFWh.png)

Are there Highcharts settings or CSS styles to enable the border to be shown all of the way around the segment when hovering over that segment?

Chart settings and JSFiddle links:

column chart: http://jsfiddle.net/nyh22g2e/1/

column chart settings:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          brightness: 0,
          borderColor: 'black',
          halo: false,
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

pie chart: http://jsfiddle.net/djpjtmzg/

pie chart settings:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          brightness: 0,
          borderColor: 'black',
          halo: false,
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some parts of the border are not visible because they're being overlapped by the "regular" border of other columns. Setting `borderWidth` to 0 in non-hover state seems to solve this issue:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        borderWidth: 0, // regular border disabled
        states: {
            hover: {
                brightness: 0,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 1 // enable border on hover
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/1kh7kvqq/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.borderWidth

---

### **Edit**

I noticed that better solution for this problem appeared on Highcharts forum: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/stacked-bar-and-pie-border-on-hover-t39961/

It uses `mouseOver` event to increase the `zIndex` of the hovered element.

**Bottom border issue:**

Removing `"clip-path"` SVG attribute for the hovered series fixes the problem:

```
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      this.update({
        zIndex: 1
      });
      this.group.attr({
        "clip-path": ""
      });
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/p9cqzs3f/

Comment: Great, that solves the issue! One quick followup question: the bottom border of the bottom segment of each stacked column is being hidden by the axis line. Is there a way to remove or slightly move the line so that the border can be shown all of the way around every segment in the column?